# How to use MVC Model binding with an Angular ng-bind attribute

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

In my view I have a tag with an `ng-bind` attribute that is showing the correct boolean value:

```
<span id="ShowFlag" name="ShowFlag" ng-bind="session.view.showFlag"></span>
```

When the form is posted on the server side I would like to bind this to a property on the relevant model.

```
public bool ShowFlag { get; set; }
```

However, this is always returning `false`, whereas the value shown in Span tag is showing correctly as `true` on the page. Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: In chrome developer console in the network tab check what you're actually posting back to the server. Maybe the answer lies there.

Comment: The issue seems to be with the MVC model binding- I can see this is being set in the property on the model to false when debugging the POST controller action.

Comment: So you're sure the actual post contains a 'true' at ShowFlag? Are other fields being correctly set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out above, you must use an input for the binding to be successful. I used the following which is now working:

```
<input type="hidden" id="ShowFlag" name="ShowFlag" ng-value="session.view.showFlag">
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're something you're missing about how AngularJs binding works.  if you want to get a value from the server into an angular model you can use Razor to get that data into JavaScript (the best place is in your Angular controller.)

Here is a quick sample I put together.

This is code from the MVC Controller. In this example we are using Model data and ViewBag data.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    dynamic model = new ExpandoObject();
    model.ShowFlag = "True";

    ViewBag.ShowFlag = "ViewBag True";
    return View(model);
}
```

This is what the view looks like including reference so Angular, JQuery and the code for the AngularJs app and controller:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h2>Sample For Stack Overflow</h2>

        <div ng-app="glennapp">
            <div ng-controller="testController">
                <input type="text" ng-model="showFlag" />
                <input type="text" ng-model="showFlag2" />

                <div>
                    <span ng-bind="showFlag" ></span>
                    <span ng-bind="showFlag2" ></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var mainApp = angular.module('glennapp', ['glennControllers']);
        var glennControllers = angular.module('glennControllers', []);
        glennControllers.controller('testController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

            $scope.showFlag = '@ViewBag.ShowFlag';
            $scope.showFlag2 = '@Model.ShowFlag';
        }]);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Another option would be to create an MVC action that returns JsonResult and then write some JavaScript to make an Ajax call and retrieve the data.

Answer (score 1):

When posting a form only input and select tag values are passed to the server
in you case `ShowFlag` is a span, so you need to make it an input:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ShowFlag" name="ShowFlag" ng-bind="session.view.showFlag"/>
```

If you are posting to server with ajax, make sure that you serialize your model properly:

for example for the following action:

```
public ActionResult (FlagsConatiner container)
{
   //
} 

public class FlagsConatiner 
{
   public bool ShowFlag { get; set; }
}
```

Serialized model should look like this:

```
{
   "ShowFlag":"true"
}
```